# React.js component run error.Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a `Fetch` component, which should send a POST request return a response content. And meanwhile I create a `NameForm` component, which generate a data to `Fetch` component to send request. My problem is when I use `this.state.result.queryResults[0]`, I got a error in chrome like this: [image]

Here is my js code:

```
        import React, {Component} from 'react';
        import Request from 'react-http-request';

        class Fetch extends React.Component {

            constructor() {
                super();
            }

            render() {
                return (
                    <Request
                        url='http://localhost:8080/path'
                        method='post'
                        accept='application/json'
                        type="application/json"
                        send={this.props.args}
                        verbose={true}
                    >
                        {
                            ({error, result, loading}) => {
                                if (loading) {
                                    return <div>loading...</div>;
                                } else {
                                    return <div>{result.text}</div>;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    </Request>
                );
            }
        }

        class NameForm extends React.Component {
            constructor() {
                super();
                this.state = {value: '', result: []};

                this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
                this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
            }

            handleChange(event) {
                this.setState({value: event.target.value});
            }

            handleSubmit(event) {
                var content = this.state.value;

                var split = content.split(/\s+/);

                var queryObject = new Object();

                queryObject.law = null;
                queryObject.character = null;
                queryObject.lawRule = null;
                if (split.length == 1) {
                    queryObject.law = split[0];
                }
                else if (split.length == 2) {
                    queryObject.law = split[0];
                    queryObject.character = split[1];
                }
                else if (split.length > 2) {
                    queryObject.law = split[0];
                    queryObject.character = split[1];
                    queryObject.lawRule = split[2];
                }
                var json = JSON.stringify(queryObject);



                this.setState({result: (<Fetch args={json}/>)});

                event.preventDefault();
            }

            render() {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <label>
                                Name:
                                <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                            </label>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                        </form>
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>GraphName</th>
                                <th>Relation</th>
                                <th>Content</th>
                                <th>KeyWord</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tboy>{this.state.result.queryResults[0]}</tboy>
                        </table>

                    </div>
                );
            }
        }

        ReactDOM.render(<NameForm/>, document.getElementById('react'))
```

And my post response is a json like this:

```
{
        "path": {
            "law": "MyLaw",
            "character": "C1",
            "lawRule": null
        },
        "queryResults": [
            {
                "graphName": "MyLaw/C1",
                "relation": "self",
                "content": "I am C1",
                "keyword": {
                    "a": 0.4296310331415849,
                    "b": 0.22019926949447058,
                    "c": 0.16514945212085294,
                    "d": 0.16514945212085294,
                }
            },
            {
                "graphName": "MyLaw/C1/C1.1",
                "relation": "child",
                "content": "I am C1.1",
                "keyword": null
            },

            {
                "graphName": "MyLaw/C1/C1.2",
                "relation": "child",
                "content": "I am C1.2",
                "keyword": null
            },
            {
                "graphName": "MyLaw/C1/C1.3",
                "relation": "child",
                "content": "I am C1.3",
                "keyword": null
            },

        ]
    }
```

Comment: what's the out put when you do `console.log(this.state.result)`

Comment: May be the component is mounted before the fetch is made or the state is updated. So the error is expected if  the state is not set. I suggest you do a check to make sure that result exists. something like this
`this.state.result?this.state.result.queryResults[0]:""`

Comment: the output is a Object, but don't contains `queryResults`, I used `this.state.result?this.state.result.queryResults[0]:""` and the page is noting. But when I use `<tboy>{this.state.result}</tboy>`, the page show json data.

Comment: That means the object you're fetching doesn't have the attribute you want. That problem is clearly not related to react. But still you have to check if the field exists to display it inside react to avoid such error.

Comment: what do you want to display if you don't have the expected data?

Comment: What troubled me is when I use `this.setState({result: (<Fetch args={json}/>)});` the result doesn't exist data from response, But if I just test `Fetch` component ,like this `ReactDOM.render(<Fetch args = {json}/>, document.getElementById('react'))`, the page can show json data。

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor, we defined the `state` initial value

```
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {value: '', result: []};

            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
            this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        }
```

So, the initial value of `result` is `[]`.

And in `handleSubmit`, you will fetch data for result.

```
        handleSubmit(event) {
            ...
            this.setState({result: (<Fetch args={json}/>)});
            ...
        }
```

So, before submitting and data being fetched, the `result` is `[]`

So, please change

```
 <tboy>{this.state.result.queryResults[0]}</tboy>
```

To

```
 <tboy>{this.state.resultthis.state.result.queryResults[0]}</tboy>
```

Comment: what does ` <tboy>{this.state.resultthis.state.result.queryResults[0]}</tboy>` mean ?

Answer (score 0):

At your initial render results state is an empty array and it remains like it till the response from fetch call is received. So

```
<tbody>{this.state.result.queryResults[0]}</tbody>
```

fails, as `result.queryResults` is undefined.

So you need a conditional check.

```
<tbody>{this.state.result.length > 0? 
     this.state.result.queryResults && 
     this.state.result.queryResults[0]: 
 null}</tbody>
```

Comment: Do like your advice and I debug my js code, when do a submit action, the `this.state.result`  don't exist `queryResults` . The page don't show data.

Answer (score 0):

It is giving you error because when first time it renders it can not find queryResult until the request hit the server.

Try this:

```
<tboy>
    {
        this.state.result.queryResults
            ?
            this.state.result.queryResults[0]
            : null
    }
</tboy>
```